# Refactoring in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following tables:

```
query_1_2014 
query_2_2014 
query_3_2014 
query_4_2014 
. 
. 
. 
query_25_2014
```

I wish to update their names by replacing 2014 with 2015.

1. How can I replace 2014 with 2015, in the query names, with a single operation?
2. Some of the queries refer to each other; how can I update all the internal references to reflect the changed query names, with a single operation?

Comment: Ouch.. First of all, I think this could be painful, and while I don't know what the requirements are, it seems a little silly if the queries are staying the same that you are required to change all of their names. You can look into the [QueryDef.SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845522.aspx) Property.

Comment: Are you talking about queries or tables?

Answer (score 0):

As I replied in your LinkedIn post: Seems like design could be better to begin with. I am guessing that the queries contain criteria based on a hard coded year. You could easily change that to be based on the current year using the date function. As in Year(Date()). 
That said, the easiest way would be Rick Fisher's Find and Replace tool. http://www.rickworld.com/